# Trying to decode Date time encoding - examples listed

Tags: delphi, datetime, decoding

I have a problem that's been getting the better of me for months now.  I have an application that I'm trying to make additions to.  In order to do so I need to decode the file structure and be able to emulate it.  I have decoded everything except the date/time field.

I believe that the hex 11 at the beginning denotes that the following is a date/time entry and so is not part of the date time.  Further, the following 8 bytes are the date time and the date/time they each produce is given.  What I don't know is how the conversion is done.

I believe the source code that produced the file was written in Delphi if that helps.

Below are 7 examples:

```
HEX Value                     Date Time Produced
--------------------------    ------------------
11 a2 97 78 0a dd 3e e4 40    07/07/2013 09:46:50 PM
11 5c 6c 32 0b dd 3e e4 40    07/07/2013 09:46:58 PM
11 67 b1 76 e0 dd 3e e4 40    07/07/2013 10:24:27 PM
11 38 a7 e1 55 bc 42 e4 40    08/07/2013 09:15:05 PM
11 d9 4e e4 58 bc 42 e4 40    08/07/2013 09:15:37 PM
11 d2 2a f9 13 49 89 dc 40    01/01/1980 03:24:15 AM
11 d4 fb 78 63 c5 42 e4 40    08/08/2013 04:02:29 AM
11 e5 01 c9 62 c5 42 e4 40    08/08/2013 04:02:21 AM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively these strings looks like the Hex representation for the Delphi  [`TDatetime`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_TDateTime.html) type which is an alias for the `Double` type (8 bytes), Where the integral part of the `TDateTime` value is the number of days that have passed since `12/30/1899` and the fractional part of the `TDateTime` value is fraction of a 24 hour day that has elapsed.

in Delphi you can parse such values using the [`HexToBin`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.HexToBin) function like so

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Classes,
  System.SysUtils;

function Decode(const HexStr: AnsiString) : TDateTime;
begin
   Assert(Length(HexStr)=16, 'Lenght must be 16');
   HexToBin(PAnsiChar(HexStr), @Result, SizeOf(TDateTime));
end;


begin
  try
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('a297780add3ee440')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('5c6c320bdd3ee440')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('67b176e0dd3ee440')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('38a7e155bc42e440')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('d94ee458bc42e440')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('d22af9134989dc40')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('d4fb7863c542e440')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('e501c962c542e440')));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

This will return

```
07-07-2013 21:46:50
07-07-2013 21:46:58
07-07-2013 22:24:27
07-08-2013 21:15:05
07-08-2013 21:15:37
01-01-1980 3:24:15
08-08-2013 4:02:29
08-08-2013 4:02:21
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Not knowing Delphi it confirms what I suspected.  I am not familiar with whether there is a difference in double from Delphi to VB but I suspect there is.  I think that can handle the transform from here now that you have confirmed that is indeed follows Delphi conventions.  If you know how the double is stored that would be nice for my effort as well but not 100% necessary as I think it's a doable task with what I have.  Thank you so much!!!  I would give you a ^  but I just joined and it won't let me.  You let me know if I can return the favor though.